# Accessing control from content page with nested master pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm really struggling with this. The problem is only with the content pages.
I am trying to access a Text Box value from one content page ("Page1.aspx") in another content page ("Page2.aspx"). I'm not sure whether it is relevant that they are the children of nested master pages, but I thought I'd throw it in.

**Page1.aspx** is a basic form with text boxes and a submit button. The text box in Page1.aspx is called "tbFirst". The submit button has the following code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="New Member Form" PostBackUrl="Page2.aspx"/>
```

**Page2.aspx** is a new form which should be populated with a textbox value from the previous page.
The second line show <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Page1.aspx" %>
For testing purposes I am using a label ("lblResult") to display my results.

Codebehind looks like this:

```
        if (PreviousPage != null)
        {
            TextBox SourceTextBox =
                (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("tbFirst");
            if (SourceTextBox != null)
            {
                lblResult.Text = SourceTextBox.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                lblResult.Text = "No text found";
            }  
        }
        else
            {
            lblResult.Text = "No Control found";
            }
        }
        }
```

The problem is that the label text in Page2.aspx says "No text found".

I think that's all the relevant info. Anyone got any ideas? I've spent the whole afternoon trawling the forums and nothing I've tried works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure whether it is relevant that they are the children of
>   nested master pages, but I thought I'd throw it in.

The `MasterPage` is exactly what's causing this issue. You cannot find a control on a page with MasterPage by using `Page.FindControl("ControlID")`, because the Page is not the [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) of the TextBox but the `ContentPlaceholder`. The only control in the page's `ControlCollection` with MasterPage  is the MasterPage itself.

**Reason**: I've recently [answered a question that describes this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8163964/284240).

Here are some ways how you can access the TextBox from Page2:

1. You might have luck with following approach(the most direct `FindControl way)`:

   ```
   Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("tbFirst");
   ```
2. Another, better approach would be to provide a public property in `Page1` that returns `tbFirst.Text`. Then you could access it in the following way from `Page2`:

   ```
   if (PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage is Page1){
       lblResult.Text = ((Page1)PreviousPage).TbFirstText;
   }
   ```
3. You could also add the `Text` as URL-Parameter, so that it's not required that `Page2's` `PreviousPage` is `Page1`.
4. Last but not least. If you use [Server.Transer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caxa892w%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) with `preserveForm` set to tue, you would be able to retrieve the value of the original page `TextBox` control by referencing `Request.Form("TbFirst")`.

**Note**: I don't recommend a [recursive FindControl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6867134/284240) approach(starting from `MasterPage`), because it would also hardwire both pages and would be

- a cause of nasty errors
- slow
- untransparent

Comment: Thanks - there are a number of juicy ideas there, I'll need to sleep first and then give it a try!

Comment: Thanks Tim. 1st (solution and variations) had already been tried many times unsuccessfully.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. 1st solution (and variations) had already been tried many times unsuccessfully. Solution 2 worked brilliantly with 3, the URL parameter. Found details of each of these solutions in [How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx) but was getting stuck trying to get one of the solutions to work. Thanks for providing clarity :-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter way better than my answer. I'm bowing out gracefully

Comment: What if I want to access a control from the content page from the MasterPage?

Comment: @SiKni8: do you really want to hardwire the `MasterPage` with _one_ content-page? You could use: `MyPage page = Page as MyPage; if(page!=null){}` in the master to check if the current content-page is your specific page(here `MyPage`). Then you just need to provide a public property with a meaningful name in the page which f.e. gets/sets the `Text` property of a `TextBox` (i discourage from exposing a complete control but only the property you need).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FindControlRecursive(this.Master, "tbFirst")` from this class.

(Put this class in App_Code)

```
using System.Web;
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ControlHelper
/// </summary>
public static class ControlHelper
{
    // Example: HtmlForm form = ControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(this.Master, "form1") as HtmlForm;
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds a Control recursively. Note finds the first match and exits
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ContainerCtl"></param>
    /// <param name="IdToFind"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Control FindControlRecursive(this Control Root, string Id)
    {
        if (Root.ID == Id)
            return Root;

        foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
        {
            Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);
            if (FoundCtl != null)
                return FoundCtl;
        }

        return null;
    }

    //ModifyControl<TextBox>(this, tb => tb.Text = "test");
    public static void ModifyControl<T>(this Control root, Action<T> action) where T : Control
    {
        if (root is T)
            action((T)root);
        foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
            ModifyControl<T>(control, action);
    }
}
```