# Reference web control's ID by passing in a string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

If I have:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then in my code-behind I can access that web control by its "ClientID":

```
txtField1.Text = "value";
```

That works, but I want an alternate way to access the same web control by reference so I tried doing it this way:

```
TextBox myTxtField = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtField" + 1);
myTxtField.Text = "value";
```

And I am getting the error: *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."* Any idea if I am doing this right or if there is another way to reference a web control's ID by passing in a string?

Comment: Interestingly, if you switch the textbox to a literal it works fine.

Comment: Hah yea I have seen behaviour like that before. I have gotten it to work now but I am disappointed that it won't update by reference - it makes a copy of the element I am trying to update.

Comment: see my answer - it works by reference for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextBox myTxtField = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtField" + 1);
```

This returns null if the control is sitting on a ContentPage of a `MasterPage`. Then you should reference it directly (as shown below).

I've written something about this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8781131/284240

Of course it would also return null if the control has another ID or if it's in another `NamingContainer` than the page(f.e. in a GridView).

Side note:

> Then in my code-behind I can access that web control by its
>   "ClientID":

```
txtField1.Text = "value";
```

`txtField1` is the `ID` not the `ClientID` and actually you're referencing the control directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid code and must work

```
TextBox myTxtField = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtField" + 1);
myTxtField.Text = "value";
```

The reasons of error might be either you don't have `asp:TextBox` with Id `"txtField1"` or the textbox control is not in your page

Comment: You're right but the compiler wants it wrapped in a try/catch or to have a check for null, which I should have picked up on from the error I got.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it doesn't like the int: call ToString() on it, as such:

```
TextBox myTxtField = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtField" + (1).ToString());
```

Comment: if you put the int into a variable first it also works:
int num = 1;
TextBox myTxtField = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtField" + num);